# Private RSA key is null

Tags: android, android-keystore

Lately, our app has been crashing on some devices (Samsung, Huawei, Xiaiomi) on Android 8 and 9.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Caused by java.security.InvalidKeyException: RSA private or public key is null
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipherRSA.engineInitInternal(OpenSSLCipherRSA.java:205)
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipherRSA.engineInit(OpenSSLCipherRSA.java:221)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2668)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2575)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2480)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:567)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:831)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:772)
```

It did not crash previously nor does happen on earlier Android versions.
What could be the cause? Maybe OS update?

Here is the code we have used for the past year:

```
PrivateKey getKeyStoreInstance() {
    try {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keystore.load(null);
        return keystore.getKey(KEYPAIR_NAME, null);
    } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading AndroidKeyStore", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Android 9 as compile version?

Comment: @ChetanJoshi Yes

Comment: @Heisenberg, can you share the code that creates the key?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android 9 as Compile version then your must take care of changes regarding Android ids.

1. `ANDROID_ID`
2. `Build.serial` (its changed new method introduced )

So if above ids used in your code to make some uniq combination of mobile fingerprint then you should make changes in your cod.

Comment: How are these variables related to the issue?

Comment: I mentioned if you are using those IDs in your code then it  should be updated else no issue.